# Is there a way reverse of what mkdir -p option does?

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I Use Ubuntu 18.04, 19.10

using `#!/bin/bash` script how to remove the directories if they are empty from far end and stop at the directory having any file/files.

say.. I have created multiple directories with the below command

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/my/sub/directories/1/2/3
```

lateron during the time I have created lot of files in all directories starting from the directory "my to 1/2/3".

After some time I have deleted all the files in the directories "my", "directories", "1", "2", "3". Note that directory `sub` is having some files..

`mkdir -p` option will see if there are parent directories in the command `mkdir -p $HOME/.local/my/sub/directories/1/2/3` and its safe.

Question: like above is there any command to see if the directories are empty and delete from far end and stop at directory `sub` I mean `$HOME/.local/my/sub`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The reversal of the `mkdir -p` command would be `rmdir -p`.  `rmdir -p` will remove the folder structure up till the folder is not empty.  You should be able to use `rmdir` instead of `mkdir` on your command:

```
rmdir -p $HOME/.local/my/sub/directories/1/2/3
```

You can also specify wildcards like if your `$HOME/.local/my/sub/` contained like `directories1`, `directories2` and `directories3` for example, it could be done as:

```
rmdir -p $HOME/.local/my/sub/directories*/1/2/3
```

or

```
rmdir -p $HOME/.local/my/sub/*/1/2/3
```

If any folder as it is removing them contains data or another folder you will receive an error message that the directory is not empty and stops.

```
rmdir: failed to remove directory '/home/user/.local/my/sub': Directory not empty
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would not exactly undo `mkdir` if you already had empty folders there before creating the folders inside.

Comment: Don't forget the ```--ignore-fail-on-non-empty``` option if using GNU tools. Otherwise you get a complaint as you noted. I wish there were a shorter spelling of it though (like maybe ```-q``` for "quiet").

Comment: @WillCrawford - as a workaround for long options like that, you could configure an alias for `rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty`. In bash or similar: `alias rmempty="rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty "`. Or a script that wraps `rmdir` adding the extra options - this is more work but that way you can add your own response to `--help` that explains what is going on.

Comment: @DavidSpillett I don't like adding a lot of aliases because I forget, frankly, and end up typing the long command anyway half the time. The other half, I don't want the extra option (usually I'll *want* an error message if rmdir fails).

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways I'd attempt this. The easy method is as follows:

```
# Command to return only empty directories in the current directory:
find . -type d -empty -print
```

Now on my version of Ubuntu, I can simply perform the following:

```
# Find empty files, and delete them:
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Otherwise, you can create some script with a logic to count files in a directory, and delete them. Here is a starting point for counting files in sub-directories:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in */ .*/ ; do 
    echo -n $i": " ; 
    (find "$i" -type f | wc -l) ; 
done
```

Comment: Of course, the parent directory *shouldn't be deleted* using these methods as it'd count the files under it, so this *should* be safe to run. I'd strongly recommend **not** running it as root, and always ensuring your `pwd` isn't going to damage your system. Make a few tests before hand as well! :)

Comment: No, `find` **will** delete parent directories if they become empty after deleting empty subdirs. So `find -empty -type d -print` and `find -empty -type d -print -delete` will not show the same number of directories.

Comment: @Åsmund sorry, I meant more *parent* directories such as `/home` won't be deleted, if there are sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

This is closer to the reverse of `mkdir -p`:

```
$ cat deldir
#!/bin/bash
[[ $# = 0 ]] && { echo "usage: ${0##*/} DIRECTORY..." >&2; exit 1; }
rc=0
while [[ $# != 0 ]] ;do
  dir=${1%/}    # in case someone specifies DIRECTORY/ out of habit
  shift
  while true ;do
    rmdir -- "$dir" || { rc=1; break; }
    [[ $dir = */* ]] || break
    dir=${dir%/*}
  done
done
exit $rc
```

Example:

```
mkdir -p a/b/c x/y/z
deldir   a/b/c x/y/z
```